# How can I get JSdoc info when using path aliases?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

If I type a relative path on an import statement everything's fine.

[image]

If I use `@` as alias for source, I lose that.

[image]

I have this in `jsconfing.json`, but this only solves getting errors for `module not found`

[image]

Comment: Please don't show code as picture but prefer copy/paste

Comment: @Elikill58 I understand the notion, but how is that relevant in this particular case?

Comment: @dili021, found a solution? Code in pictures cannot be searched.